# DOS variable not echo'ing or concatenating

Tags: batch-file

`ECHO %filenameWithoutPGPExt%`: this line doesn't show anything in the `cmd` prompt. It also doesn't concat in the`gpg.exe` line. Any ideas?

```
FOR %%F in (%inputDir%\\Invoices*.pgp) DO ( 
    SET fName=%%F
    SET filenameWithoutPGPExt=%%~nF

    ECHO %filenameWithoutPGPExt%

    C:\GnuPG\gpg.exe --batch --yes --output %outFilename%%filenameWithoutPGPExt% --passphrase-fd <C:\\GnuPG\\pasfraz.txt --decrypt %%F 
)
```

Comment: this is NOT DOS.

Comment: Does the loop run at all? Why? What is `%inputDir%`, and what matching filenames are in there?

Comment: [cmd is not DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's no support for `for /f` and `%%~nF`. The use of double slashes is also useless because backslash is not an escape character there

Comment: Why are you bothering with creating an environmental variable of the base file name.  You can just use the FOR variable directly with your `GPG` command. `--output %outFilename%%%~nF`

Comment: @Squashman That works. Not sure why the variable part didn't but that does. Thanks.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard My apologies.

Comment: @user441521, the answer below shows you that you need to use delayed expansion with your variables when you are inside a parenthesized code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go. You can change `D:\dir` at `inputdir` variable.

```
@echo off
set "inputdir=D:\dir"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%F in (%inputDir%\Invoices*.pgp) DO ( 
    SET "fName=%%F"
    SET "filenameWithoutPGPExt=%%~nF"
    ECHO !filenameWithoutPGPExt!
    C:\GnuPG\gpg.exe --batch --yes --output %outFilename%!filenameWithoutPGPExt! --passphrase-fd <C:\\GnuPG\\pasfraz.txt --decrypt %%F 
)
```

You also do not need to set a variable, unless used elsewhere aswell.. Below demonstrates that the values will remain the same as if you set a variable.

```
FOR %%F in (%inputDir%\Invoices*.pgp) DO ( 
    echo %%F
    echo %%~nF
)
```

Comment: Need to change the variable in the `GPG` command with the --output option as well.